# Show by induction on $n$ that:

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, proof-writing, induction

$$1^4 + 2^4 +\cdots+n^4=\frac{n^5}{5}+\frac{n^4}{2}+\frac{n^3}{3}-\frac{n}{30}$$

I proved true for case $n=1$ , assumed true for $n=k$ , but cannot get things to work out. I tried putting the right side over a common denominator and going from there but I'm sure how much it helps.

Comment: You need to use the binomial theorem to cancel out things between the $(n+1)^4$ and the new terms appearing in the right. That's all.

Comment: @Byong Please show us what you've done exactly.

Answer (score 4):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k^{4}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{4}+\left(n+1\right)^{4}=\frac{n^{5}}{5}+\frac{n^{4}}{2}+\frac{n^{3}}{3}-\frac{n}{30}+n^{4}+4n^{3}+6n^{2}+4n+1
 $$$$=\frac{6n^{5}+15n^{4}+10n^{3}-n}{30}+\frac{30n^{4}+120n^{3}+180n^{2}+120n+30}{30}=\frac{6n^{5}+45n^{4}+130n^{3}+180n^{2}+119n+30}{30}$$
 and see that$$6\left(n+1\right)^{5}+15\left(n+1\right)^{4}+10\left(n+1\right)^{3}-\left(n+1\right)$$$$=\left(6n^{5}+30n^{4}+60n^{3}+60n^{2}+30n+6\right)
 +\left(15n^{4}+60n^{3}+90n^{2}+60n+15\right)+\left(10n^{3}+30n^{2}+30n+10\right)-n-1=6n^{5}+45n^{4}+130n^{3}+180n^{2}+119n+30.$$

Comment: Hi Nicolas, thanks so much. I'm just a little confused as to the portion below "and see that".. I understand why we go about it this way, but am not clear what the "punchline" proving it is so to speak

Comment: Hi Byong. The last part "see that" is a calculus to recognize the last numerator before this remark. But you are right, I knew what I had to find out, and calculated consequently - this is induction, isn't it?-

Comment: Yes, it is induction. How did you go from the numerator above the "see that" portion to the portion below, as one raises n to an exponent and the other raises (n+1)? When I worked it out on my own, I started the same as you calculating the left side as you did, and then used the binomial theorem for each portion of the right hand side setting y=1 and then once I had the left and right hand sides started canceling out. Is that valid?

Comment: I just used the Pascal triangle to deduce that$$\left(a+b\right)^{5}=a^{5}+5a^{4}b+10a^{3}b^{2}+10a^{2}b^{3}+5ab^{4}+b^{5},$$
  $$\left(a+b\right)^{4}=a^{4}+4a^{3}b+6a^{2}b^{2}+4ab^{3}+b^{4},$$
  $$\left(a+b\right)^{3}=a^{3}+43a^{2}b+3ab^{2}+b^{3}.$$

These are the same formula than derivated from binomial ones.

Comment: Another approach you can use (basically the same answer) is to convert all of the $n$s to $(n+1)$s. $$\begin{array}{lll}
\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{4}&=&\displaystyle\frac{n^{5}}{5}+\frac{n^{4}}{2}+\frac{n^{3}}{3}-\frac{n}{30}\\
&=&\displaystyle\frac{((n+1)-1)^{5}}{5}+\frac{((n+1)-1)^{4}}{2}+\frac{((n+1)-1)^{3}}{3}-\frac{((n+1)-1)}{30}\\
&=&\dots\\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

**First, show that this is true for $n=1$:**

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{1}k^4=\frac{6\cdot1^5+15\cdot1^4+10\cdot1^3-1}{30}$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}k^4=\frac{6n^5+15n^4+10n^3-n}{30}$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}k^4=$

$\color{red}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}k^4}+(n+1)^4=$

$\color{red}{\frac{6n^5+15n^4+10n^3-n}{30}}+(n+1)^4=$

$\frac{6n^5+15n^4+10n^3-n}{30}+n^4+4n^3+6n^2+4n+1=$

$\frac{6n^5+15n^4+10n^3-n}{30}+\frac{30n^4+120n^3+180n^2+120n+30}{30}=$

$\frac{6n^5+45n^4+130n^3+180n^2+119n+30}{30}=$

$\frac{6(n+1)^5+15(n+1)^4+10(n+1)^3-(n+1)}{30}$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.